# HTML5 Autocomplete <datalist> can work with Ajax on AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, html-datalist

I'm trying to working with default HTML5 datalist tag to implement a simple autocomplete in a AngularJS App. This is a simple view file with an input text and datalist control:

```
<input type="text" list="players" ng-model="automplete_player_text" ng-change="getPlayersList()">

<datalist id="players">
<option value="{{player.surname}}" ng-repeat="player in players">{{player.name}}</option>
</datalist>
```

Then a simple method in the page controller that get data with "string" query from server and render result into players through NgResource service:

```
function getPlayersList(){
        RealPlayer.query({..},
            function(data){ 
                $scope.players = data;
            }
        );
    }
```

The problem is that getPlayersList() is asyncronous so, each time that I digit some letter browser renders correctly the <option> into <datalist> but it doesn't show the list UI, probably becouse when it searchs options are not yet rendered.

Was HTML5 datalist thought to filter results only on the client (memory) ?

Comment: Have you tried using ng-options instead of ng-repeat? It would be ng-options="player.surname as player.name for player in players" in your case. It might be worth a try

Comment: I tried but it seems the same...